# Laravel: Check on which form submitted the request

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

On my website, users can display posts created by other users. However, I have 2 select boxes, one for ordering by name or date and the other is ordering by category. The way I have done it is incorrect and I am aware of that. The simple reason for this is that I don't know how to make an if check on which form submitted the request.

Here is my controller method for displaying the events:

```
public function getEvents(Request $request){
    if($request['sort'] == "created_at"){
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    }
    elseif($request['sort'] == "title"){
        $posts = Post::orderBy('title', 'desc')->get();
    }
    elseif($request['category'] == "sport"){
        $post = Post::where('type', '=', 'sport' )->get();
    }
    elseif($request['category'] == "culture"){
        $post = Post::where('type', '=', 'culture' )->get();
    }
    elseif($request['category'] == "other"){
        $post = Post::where('type', '=', 'other' )->get();
    }
    else{
        $posts = Post::orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->get();
    }

    return view ('eventspage',  ['posts' => $posts]);
}
```

This is currently incorrect, I want it to follow this structure:

```
if(request submitted by 'sort')
   then do this...
elseif(request submitted by 'category')
   then do this...
```

Here is my view containing the 2 select boxes:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form action="{{ route('events') }}">
            <select name="category" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control">
                <option value="sport">sport</option>
                <option value="culture">Culture</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <form action="{{ route('events') }}">    
            <select name="sort" onchange="this.form.submit()" class="form-control">
                <option value="created_at">Date</option>
                <option value="title">Title</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Make different actions for forms? And write two different routes in routes/web.php.

Comment: Can you specify if you are using Laravel 4 or 5 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a hidden input in your form with name as `formName` and the respective values.

Then it's easy to check which form submitted.

```
//Category form
<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="category">

//Sort form
<input type="hidden" name="formName" value="sort">
```

Then, in the controller:

```
if($request['formName'] == 'category') //request submitted by 'category'
   //then do this...
elseif($request['formName'] == 'sort')  //request submitted by 'sort'
   //then do this...
```

Just be careful not to put too much different code in both conditionals. If you find yourself having two entirely different functions, create an action for each form.

Comment: I get the error 'Undefined variable: posts' pointing at the line. return view ('eventspage',  ['posts' => $posts]); Is there a reason it is not entering any of my if blocks when selecting a category.

Comment: because there you're making a `$post` variable, not `$posts`.

Comment: Not sure how I didn't spot that. It works, thank you.